# XML File Parsing Error

Tags: javascript, xml

I have this XML file and when I try to parse it, it gives me the error.

> The ';' character, hexadecimal value 0x3B, cannot be included in a name

Here is the code in the XML file, would someone please tell me how to fix it? Thank you for your help.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.NREUM || (NREUM = {});
    NREUM.info = {
        "beacon": "bam.xxxxxxxxx.net",
        "errorBeacon": "bam.xxxxxxxxx.net",
        "licenseKey": "4xxxxxxxx",
        "applicationID": "2xxxxxxx",
        "transactionName": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx==",
        "queueTime": 0,
        "applicationTime": 1xxxxxx,
        "agent": "",
        "atts": ""
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.NREUM || (NREUM = {}), __nr_require = function(e, n, t) {
        function r(t) {
            if (!n[t]) {
                var o = n[t] = {
                    exports: {}
                };
                e[t][0].call(o.exports, function(n) {
                    var o = e[t][1][n];
                    return r(o || n)
                }, o, o.exports)
            }
            return n[t].exports
        }
        if ("function" == typeof __nr_require) return __nr_require;
        for (var o = 0; o < t.length; o++) r(t[o]);
        return r
    }({
        1: [function(e, n, t) {
            function r() {}

            function o(e, n, t) {
                return function() {
                    return i(e, [c.now()].concat(u(arguments)), n ? null : this, t), n ? void 0 : this
                }
            }
            var i = e("handle"),
                a = e(2),
                u = e(3),
                f = e("ee").get("tracer"),
                c = e("loader"),
                s = NREUM;
            "undefined" == typeof window.newrelic && (newrelic = s);
            var p = ["setPageViewName", "setCustomAttribute", "setErrorHandler", "finished", "addToTrace", "inlineHit", "addRelease"],
                d = "api-",
                l = d + "ixn-";
            a(p, function(e, n) {
                s[n] = o(d + n, !0, "api")
            }), s.addPageAction = o(d + "addPageAction", !0), s.setCurrentRouteName = o(d + "routeName", !0), n.exports = newrelic, s.interaction = function() {
                return (new r).get()
            };
            var m = r.prototype = {
                createTracer: function(e, n) {
                    var t = {},
                        r = this,
                        o = "function" == typeof n;
                    return i(l + "tracer", [c.now(), e, t], r),
                        function() {
                            if (f.emit((o ? "" : "no-") + "fn-start", [c.now(), r, o], t), o) try {
                                return n.apply(this, arguments)
                            } finally {
                                f.emit("fn-end", [c.now()], t)
                            }
                        }
                }
            };
            a("setName,setAttribute,save,ignore,onEnd,getContext,end,get".split(","), function(e, n) {
                m[n] = o(l + n)
            }), newrelic.noticeError = function(e) {
                "string" == typeof e && (e = new Error(e)), i("err", [e, c.now()])
            }
        }, {}],
        2: [function(e, n, t) {
            function r(e, n) {
                var t = [],
                    r = "",
                    i = 0;
                for (r in e) o.call(e, r) && (t[i] = n(r, e[r]), i += 1);
                return t
            }
            var o = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty;
            n.exports = r
        }, {}],
        3: [function(e, n, t) {
            function r(e, n, t) {
                n || (n = 0), "undefined" == typeof t && (t = e ? e.length : 0);
                for (var r = -1, o = t - n || 0, i = Array(o < 0 ? 0 : o); ++r < o;) i[r] = e[n + r];
                return i
            }
            n.exports = r
        }, {}],
        4: [function(e, n, t) {
            n.exports = {
                exists: "undefined" != typeof window.performance && window.performance.timing && "undefined" != typeof window.performance.timing.navigationStart
            }
        }, {}],
        ee: [function(e, n, t) {
            function r() {}

            function o(e) {
                function n(e) {
                    return e && e instanceof r ? e : e ? f(e, u, i) : i()
                }

                function t(t, r, o, i) {
                    if (!d.aborted || i) {
                        e && e(t, r, o);
                        for (var a = n(o), u = m(t), f = u.length, c = 0; c < f; c++) u[c].apply(a, r);
                        var p = s[y[t]];
                        return p && p.push([b, t, r, a]), a
                    }
                }

                function l(e, n) {
                    v[e] = m(e).concat(n)
                }

                function m(e) {
                    return v[e] || []
                }

                function w(e) {
                    return p[e] = p[e] || o(t)
                }

                function g(e, n) {
                    c(e, function(e, t) {
                        n = n || "feature", y[t] = n, n in s || (s[n] = [])
                    })
                }
                var v = {},
                    y = {},
                    b = {
                        on: l,
                        emit: t,
                        get: w,
                        listeners: m,
                        context: n,
                        buffer: g,
                        abort: a,
                        aborted: !1
                    };
                return b
            }

            function i() {
                return new r
            }

            function a() {
                (s.api || s.feature) && (d.aborted = !0, s = d.backlog = {})
            }
            var u = "nr@context",
                f = e("gos"),
                c = e(2),
                s = {},
                p = {},
                d = n.exports = o();
            d.backlog = s
        }, {}],
        gos: [function(e, n, t) {
            function r(e, n, t) {
                if (o.call(e, n)) return e[n];
                var r = t();
                if (Object.defineProperty && Object.keys) try {
                    return Object.defineProperty(e, n, {
                        value: r,
                        writable: !0,
                        enumerable: !1
                    }), r
                } catch (i) {}
                return e[n] = r, r
            }
            var o = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty;
            n.exports = r
        }, {}],
        handle: [function(e, n, t) {
            function r(e, n, t, r) {
                o.buffer([e], r), o.emit(e, n, t)
            }
            var o = e("ee").get("handle");
            n.exports = r, r.ee = o
        }, {}],
        id: [function(e, n, t) {
            function r(e) {
                var n = typeof e;
                return !e || "object" !== n && "function" !== n ? -1 : e === window ? 0 : a(e, i, function() {
                    return o++
                })
            }
            var o = 1,
                i = "nr@id",
                a = e("gos");
            n.exports = r
        }, {}],
        loader: [function(e, n, t) {
            function r() {
                if (!x++) {
                    var e = h.info = NREUM.info,
                        n = d.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
                    if (setTimeout(s.abort, 3e4), !(e && e.licenseKey && e.applicationID && n)) return s.abort();
                    c(y, function(n, t) {
                        e[n] || (e[n] = t)
                    }), f("mark", ["onload", a() + h.offset], null, "api");
                    var t = d.createElement("script");
                    t.src = "https://" + e.agent, n.parentNode.insertBefore(t, n)
                }
            }

            function o() {
                "complete" === d.readyState && i()
            }

            function i() {
                f("mark", ["domContent", a() + h.offset], null, "api")
            }

            function a() {
                return E.exists && performance.now ? Math.round(performance.now()) : (u = Math.max((new Date).getTime(), u)) - h.offset
            }
            var u = (new Date).getTime(),
                f = e("handle"),
                c = e(2),
                s = e("ee"),
                p = window,
                d = p.document,
                l = "addEventListener",
                m = "attachEvent",
                w = p.XMLHttpRequest,
                g = w && w.prototype;
            NREUM.o = {
                ST: setTimeout,
                CT: clearTimeout,
                XHR: w,
                REQ: p.Request,
                EV: p.Event,
                PR: p.Promise,
                MO: p.MutationObserver
            };
            var v = "" + location,
                y = {
                    beacon: "bam.xxxxxxxxx.net",
                    errorBeacon: "bam.xxxxxxxxx.net",
                    agent: "js-agent.newrelic.com/nr-1026.min.js"
                },
                b = w && g && g[l] && !/CriOS/.test(navigator.userAgent),
                h = n.exports = {
                    offset: u,
                    now: a,
                    origin: v,
                    features: {},
                    xhrWrappable: b
                };
            e(1), d[l] ? (d[l]("DOMContentLoaded", i, !1), p[l]("load", r, !1)) : (d[m]("onreadystatechange", o), p[m]("onload", r)), f("mark", ["firstbyte", u], null, "api");
            var x = 0,
                E = e(4)
        }, {}]
    }, {}, ["loader"]);
</script>
    <title>Runtime Error</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <style>
     body {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size: .7em;color:black;} 
     p {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
     b {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:bold;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
     H1 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:18pt;color:red }
     H2 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:14pt;color:maroon }
     pre {font-family:"Consolas","Lucida Console",Monospace;font-size:11pt;margin:0;padding:0.5em;line-height:14pt}
     .marker {font-weight: bold; color: black;text-decoration: none;}
     .version {color: gray;}
     .error {margin-bottom: 10px;}
     .expandable { text-decoration:underline; font-weight:bold; color:navy; cursor:hand; }
     @media screen and (max-width: 639px) {
      pre { width: 440px; overflow: auto; white-space: pre-wrap; word-wrap: break-word; }
     }
     @media screen and (max-width: 479px) {
      pre { width: 280px; }
     }
    </style>
</head>

<body bgcolor="white">

        <span><H1>Server Error in '/TeamAPI' Application.<hr width=100% size=1 color=silver></H1>

        <h2> <i>Runtime Error</i> </h2></span>

        <font face="Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, SunSans-Regular, sans-serif ">

        <b> Description: </b>An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.
        <br><br>

        <b>Details:</b> To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a &lt;customErrors&gt; tag within a &quot;web.config&quot; configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This &lt;customErrors&gt; tag should then have its &quot;mode&quot; attribute set to &quot;Off&quot;.<br><br>

        <table width=100% bgcolor="#ffffcc">
           <tr>
              <td>
                  <code><pre>

&lt;!-- Web.Config Configuration File --&gt;

&lt;configuration&gt;
    &lt;system.web&gt;
        &lt;customErrors mode=&quot;Off&quot;/&gt;
    &lt;/system.web&gt;
&lt;/configuration&gt;</pre></code>

                  </td>
               </tr>
            </table>

            <br>

            <b>Notes:</b> The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a custom error page by modifying the &quot;defaultRedirect&quot; attribute of the application&#39;s &lt;customErrors&gt; configuration tag to point to a custom error page URL.<br><br>

            <table width=100% bgcolor="#ffffcc">
               <tr>
                  <td>
                      <code><pre>

&lt;!-- Web.Config Configuration File --&gt;

&lt;configuration&gt;
    &lt;system.web&gt;
        &lt;customErrors mode=&quot;RemoteOnly&quot; defaultRedirect=&quot;mycustompage.htm&quot;/&gt;
    &lt;/system.web&gt;
&lt;/configuration&gt;</pre></code>

                  </td>
               </tr>
            </table>

            <br>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's probably complaining about this:

```
< t.length;
```

It treats the `<` as indicating that an element start tag is expected; then it reads characters up to a space character to find the element name; it then validates `t.length;` as an element name, and reports it as invalid because a name can't contain a semicolon.

Either escape the `<` as `&lt;` (and likewise any other occurrences of `<` or `&`; or enclose the content of the script elements in CDATA:

```
<script type="text/javascript"><![CDATA[.....]]></script>
```